# QStringList.indexOf() not returning correct value

Tags: c++, qt

I have a line in a file which is like this:

```
DEF PatientLoadView Group {
```

I am trying to parse the file to get the word after the word "DEF" in the above line.
I am trying to find split the line using string.split() and then use indexOf function of QStringList class to find the index of "DEF" and then get the word next to it. But the indexOf function returns -1 for this line. For other such lines, it returns correct value. What could be the problem?
My code is as follows:

```
QString line = in.readLine();
if(line.contains("DEF"))
{
    QStringList lineSplit = line.split(" ");
    int index = lineSplit.indexOf("DEF",0);
    QString nodeName = lineSplit[index+1];
```

Comment: 'line' contains "DEF PatientLoadView Group {"

Comment: It seems to be worked for me and `nodeName` contains `PatientLoadView`. You can try to use `qDebug` to get more control over execution.

Comment: Does `QString line = "DEF PatientLoadView Group {";` work?

Comment: I agree with @fasked, get it to print out the contents of `lineSplit`.

Comment: Space between DEG and next word could be a tabulation symbol. Which looks like a space, if your tab size is equal to 4. So string isn't splitted by space in that position. Hence index of DEG couldn't be found and -1 is returned. So you better simplify your string before splitting. I'd also recommend you to to handle such situation as having those words in different lines, if you are writing such parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause of the problem - the line starts with a tab '\t' and that was being part of the string that I read in. Removing this tab character worked fine for me and I am now able to get the correct results.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Make certain there's nothing before the `DEF` characters in `line`.

In particular, make sure there's no '\n' or other control characters.